# Python - Grab specific value from known key inside large json

Tags: python, json

I need to get just 2 entries inside a very large `json` object, I don't know the array position, but I do know key:value pairs of the entry I want to find and where I want another value from this entry.

In this example there are only 4 examples, but in the original there are over 1000, and I need only 2 entries of which I do know "name" and "symbol" each. I need to get the value of **quotes->ASK->time**.

```
x = requests.get('http://example.org/data.json')
parsed = x.json()

gettime= str(parsed[0]["quotes"]["ASK"]["time"])
print(gettime)
```

I know that I can get it that way, and then loop through that a thousand times, but that seems like an overkill for just 2 values. Is there a way to do something like **`parsed["symbol":"kalo"]["quotes"]["ASK"]["time"]`** which would give me `kalo` time without using a loop, without going through all thousand entries?

```
[
  {
    "id": "nem-cri",
    "name": "nemlaaoo",
    "symbol": "nem",
    "rank": 27,
    "owner": "marcel",
    "quotes": {
      "ASK": {
        "price": 19429,
        "time": 319250866,
        "duration": 21
      }
    }
  },
 {
    "id": "kalo-lo-leek",
    "name": "kalowaaa",
    "symbol": "kalo",
    "rank": 122,
    "owner": "daniel",
    "quotes": {
      "ASK": {
        "price": 12928,
        "time": 937282932,
        "duration": 09
      }
    }
  },
 {
    "id": "reewmaarwl",
    "name": "reeqooow",
    "symbol": "reeq",
    "rank": 4,
    "owner": "eric",
    "quotes": {
      "ASK": {
        "price": 9989,
        "time": 124288222,
        "duration": 19
      }
    }
  },
 {
    "id": "sharkooaksj",
    "name": "sharkmaaa",
    "symbol": "shark",
    "rank": 22,
    "owner": "eric",
    "quotes": {
      "ASK": {
        "price": 11122,
        "time": 482773882,
        "duration": 22
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: There's no way round it. Your code (or some other code) is going to have to search for the right symbol. Is there a way of accessing it directly through a query when you call `requests.get()`, or get the data indexed by symbol?

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with using pandas I would just create a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(parsed)
print(df)

             id       name symbol  rank   owner  quotes.ASK.price  \
0       nem-cri   nemlaaoo    nem    27  marcel             19429   
1  kalo-lo-leek   kalowaaa   kalo   122  daniel             12928   
2    reewmaarwl   reeqooow   reeq     4    eric              9989   
3   sharkooaksj  sharkmaaa  shark    22    eric             11122   

   quotes.ASK.time  quotes.ASK.duration  
0        319250866                   21  
1        937282932                    9  
2        124288222                   19  
3        482773882                   22
```

If you want the kalo value then

```
print(df[df['symbol'] == 'kalo']['quotes.ASK.price'])  # -> 12928
```